# Qt / C++/ Warehouse Club Management System

Tags: c++, qt

I am building a primitive Store Management System based on Qt and would appreciate some feedback.

Classes:

- `ManagementSystem` - the logic unit of the system
- `User` - might be either Admin or Manager (they access the system)
- `Member` - the people who are the members of the Warehouse Club. Might be either Executive (obtains 3% of rebate from every purchase) and Regular.
- `MainWindow` - view layer of the system.
- `Sale` - stores one sale unit (item + quantity)
- `Item` - stores the name of the item, its price and how many of the has been sold so far.
  I am using only one window and show or hide the respective elements depending on the context.

Data Storage:

- 7 day sales txt files. For every file (line by line):

  - Purchase date
  - Customer membership number
  - Item purchased
  - [Sales price] [quantity purchased] (in one line)
- Members txt file (line by line) :

  - Customer name
  - Customer membership number
  - Type of customer – Regular or Executive
  - Membership expiration date
- Users txt file (line by line):

  - login
  - password

ManagementSystem.h

```
#ifndef MANAGEMENTSYSTEM_H
#define MANAGEMENTSYSTEM_H

#include "user.h"
#include "member.h"
#include "item.h"
#include "sale.h"
#include <QFile>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QVector>
#include <functional>


#define CREDENTIALS_FILE "/home/dominik/projects/study/BulkClub/BulkClub/login.txt"
#define DAY1_FILE "/home/dominik/projects/study/BulkClub/BulkClub/resources/day1.txt"
#define DAY2_FILE "/home/dominik/projects/study/BulkClub/BulkClub/resources/day2.txt"
#define DAY3_FILE "/home/dominik/projects/study/BulkClub/BulkClub/resources/day3.txt"
#define DAY4_FILE "/home/dominik/projects/study/BulkClub/BulkClub/resources/day4.txt"
#define DAY5_FILE "/home/dominik/projects/study/BulkClub/BulkClub/resources/day5.txt"
#define DAY6_FILE "/home/dominik/projects/study/BulkClub/BulkClub/resources/day6.txt"
#define DAY7_FILE "/home/dominik/projects/study/BulkClub/BulkClub/resources/day7.txt"
#define MEMBERS_FILE "/home/dominik/projects/study/BulkClub/BulkClub/resources/warehouse shoppers.txt"
#define TMP_FILE "/home/dominik/projects/study/BulkClub/BulkClub/resources/tmp.txt"

#define LINES_MEMBERS 4
#define LINES_SALES 4

enum CurrentlyLogged {
    noOne, admin, manager
};

class ManagementSystem
{
public:
    ManagementSystem();
    void initializeUsers();
    bool retrieveCredentials();
    User getAdmin() const {return admin;}
    User getManager() const {return manager;}
    QVector<QVector<Sale>> getSales() const {return m_allSales;}
    QVector<Member> getMembers() const {return m_members;}
    CurrentlyLogged getCurrentlyLogged() const { return logged;}
    void setCurrentlyLogged(CurrentlyLogged log) {logged=log;}
    void setMembers(QVector<Member>& mem) {m_members=mem;}
    bool populateMembersData(QFile& file);
    bool populateDaySales(QFile* file);
    void sortPurchasesByNumber();
    Member* findMember(int id);
    void sortMembers(bool is_byID);
    QVector<int> getExecutiveMembers() const {return m_executiveMembers;}
    QVector<int> getRegularMembers() const {return m_regularMembers;}
    QVector<Sale> getAllSalesOneVec() const {return m_allSalesOneVec;}
    QVector<Item*> getAllItems() const { return m_allItems;}
    void addMemberToFile(Member& m);
    //void deleteMemberFromFile(QString& member_name);
private:
    User admin;
    User manager;
    QVector<Member> m_members;
    CurrentlyLogged logged;//0=no one, 1=admin, 2=manager
    QVector<QVector<Sale>> m_allSales;
    QVector<Sale> m_allSalesOneVec;
    QFile* m_salesFiles[7];
    QVector<int> m_executiveMembers;
    QVector<int> m_regularMembers;
    QVector<Item*> m_allItems;
    QVector<QString> m_allItemsNames;
};

#endif // MANAGEMENTSYSTEM_H
```

Member.h :

```
#ifndef MEMBER_H
#define MEMBER_H
#include <QDateTime>
enum MembershipType {
    Executive, Regular
};

class Member
{
public:
    Member();
    Member(QString name, int no, MembershipType type, QDate date, int total, int rebate);

    QString getName() const {return m_name;}
    int getNumber() const {return m_number;}
    MembershipType getType() const {return m_type;}
    QDate getDate() const {return m_date;}
    int getTotalSpent() const {return m_totalSpent;}
    int getRebate() const {return m_rebateAmount;}

    void setName(QString name) {m_name = name;}
    void setNumber(int number) {m_number = number;}
    void setType(MembershipType type) {m_type = type;}
    void setDate(QDate date) {m_date = date;}
    void setTotalSpent(int spent) {m_totalSpent = spent;}
    void setRebate(int rebate) {m_rebateAmount = rebate;}



private:
    QString m_name;
    int m_number;
    MembershipType m_type;
    QDate m_date;
    int m_totalSpent=0; //in cents
    int m_rebateAmount=0;

};



#endif // MEMBER_H
```

Sale.h

```
#ifndef SALE_H
#define SALE_H
#include "member.h"
#include "item.h"
#include <QFile>
#include <QDate>
const float REBATE_PERCENT = 0.03;

class Sale
{
public:
    Sale();
    int getQuantity() const {return m_quantity;}

    int getMembersID() const {return m_number;}
    QDate getDate() const {return m_date;}
    Item* getItem() {return m_item;}
    void setMembersID(int number) {m_number=number;}
    void setQuantity(int q) {m_quantity=q;}
    void setDate(QDate date) {m_date=date;}
    int getPriceBeforeTax() const {return m_item->getPrice()*(1-sales_tax);}
    void setItem(Item* it) {m_item=it;}

private:
    QDate m_date;
    int m_number;
    Item* m_item;
    int m_quantity;
    static int sales_tax;
};

#endif // SALE_H
```

User.h

```
void setIsAdmin(bool is) {m_isAdmin = is;}
void setLogin(int login) {m_loginID = login;}
void setPsw(QString psw) {m_password = psw;}
void setLoggedNow(bool logged) {m_loggedNow = logged;}

bool getIsAdmin() const {return m_isAdmin;}
int getLogin() const {return m_loginID;}
QString getPsw() const {return m_password;}
bool getLoggedNow() const {return m_loggedNow;}
private:
    bool m_isAdmin; //if true -> admin, if false -> store manager
    int m_loginID;
    QString m_password;
    bool m_loggedNow;

};
#endif // USER_H
```

Item.h

```
#ifndef ITEM_H
#define ITEM_H
#include <QString>
class Item
{
public:
    Item();
    int getPrice() const {return m_price;}
    QString getName() const {
        return m_name;
    }
    void setName(QString it) {m_name=it;}
    void setPrice(int price) {m_price=price;}
    int getCount() const {return count;}
    void setCount(int c) {count = c;}
private:
    QString m_name;
    int m_price;
    int count=0;
};

#endif // ITEM_H
```

ManagementSystem.cpp

```
#include "managementsystem.h"
static int ccc=0;
ManagementSystem::ManagementSystem()
{
    QFile file(MEMBERS_FILE);
    m_salesFiles[0] = new QFile (DAY1_FILE);
    m_salesFiles[1] = new QFile (DAY2_FILE);
    m_salesFiles[2] = new QFile (DAY3_FILE);
    m_salesFiles[3] = new QFile (DAY4_FILE);
    m_salesFiles[4] = new QFile (DAY5_FILE);
    m_salesFiles[5] = new QFile (DAY6_FILE);
    m_salesFiles[6] = new QFile (DAY7_FILE);

    initializeUsers();
    retrieveCredentials();
    populateMembersData(file);

    //store IDs of regular and executive members in 2 vectors
    for(auto& mem : m_members) {
        if(mem.getType()==1) m_regularMembers.push_back(mem.getNumber());
        else if(mem.getType()==0) m_executiveMembers.push_back(mem.getNumber());
    }

    //populate days data from 7 files
    for(QFile* f : m_salesFiles) {
        populateDaySales(f);
    }
}

//users init
void ManagementSystem::initializeUsers() {
    manager = User(false, 0, "");
    admin = User(true, 0, "");
}

//initialize admin and user
bool ManagementSystem::retrieveCredentials() {
    int counter=0;
    QFile credentials_file(CREDENTIALS_FILE);
    if(credentials_file.exists()){
        if (!credentials_file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)) {
            qDebug() << manager.getLogin();
            return false;
        }
        while (!credentials_file.atEnd()) {
            bool encoding;
            QByteArray line = credentials_file.readLine();
            line = line.trimmed();
            if(counter==0) manager.setLogin(QString(line).toInt(&encoding, 10));
            if(counter==1) manager.setPsw(QString(line));
            if(counter==2) admin.setLogin(QString(line).toInt(&encoding, 10));
            if(counter==3) admin.setPsw(QString(line));
            counter++;
        }
        return true;
    }
    else {
        qDebug() << "File doesnt exists";
        return false;
    }
}

//populate members data from file
bool ManagementSystem::populateMembersData(QFile& file){
    Member* mem;
    MembershipType type;
    QString name_buf;
    int number_buf;
    MembershipType type_buf;
    QDate date_buf;

    int counter=0;
    if(file.exists()){
        if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)) {
            qInfo() << "STH WENT WRONG";
            return false;
        }
        while (!file.atEnd()) {
            bool encoding;
            QByteArray line = file.readLine();
            line = line.trimmed();
            if(counter%LINES_MEMBERS==0) {
                name_buf = QString(line);
            }
            else if((counter+3)%LINES_MEMBERS==0) {
                number_buf = QString(line).toInt(&encoding, 10);

            }
            else if((counter+2)%LINES_MEMBERS==0) {

                if(line.operator == ("Regular")) {
                    type_buf = MembershipType::Regular;
                }
                if(line.operator == ("Executive")) {
                    type_buf = MembershipType::Executive;
                }
            }
            else if((counter+1)%LINES_MEMBERS==0) {
                QString date_str = QString(line);
                date_buf = QDate::fromString(date_str,"MM/dd/yyyy");
                mem = new Member;
                mem->setDate(date_buf);
                mem->setName(name_buf);
                mem->setNumber(number_buf);
                mem->setType(type_buf);
                m_members.push_back(*mem);
                delete mem;
            }
            counter++;
        }
    }
    else {
        qDebug() << "File doesnt exists";
        return false;
    }
}



bool ManagementSystem::populateDaySales(QFile* file) {

        QVector<Sale> day_vector;
        int lines_number=4;
        Sale* sale;
        Item* item;
        int number_buf;
        QDate date_buf;
        QString item_buf;
        QString item_line_buf;
        int item_price_buf;
        int quantity_buf;
        int counter=0;
        if(file->exists()){
            if (!file->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)) {
                qDebug() << "Populate Day sales doesnt work";
                return false;
            }
            while (!file->atEnd()) {
                bool encoding;
                QByteArray line = file->readLine();
                line = line.trimmed();

                if(counter % LINES_SALES==0) {
                    QString date_str = QString(line);
                    date_buf = QDate::fromString(date_str,"MM/dd/yyyy");
                }
                else if((counter+3) % LINES_SALES==0) {
                    number_buf = QString(line).toInt(&encoding, 10);

                }
                else if((counter+2) % LINES_SALES==0) {
                    item_buf = QString(line);
                }
                else if((counter+1) % LINES_SALES==0) {

                    QStringList list;
                    list = QString(line).split('\t');
                    item_price_buf = static_cast<int>(QString(list[0]).toFloat()*100);
                    quantity_buf = QString(list[1]).toInt();
                    sale = new Sale;
                    sale->setDate(date_buf);
                    sale->setQuantity(quantity_buf);
                    sale->setMembersID(number_buf);

                    int i = m_allItemsNames.indexOf(item_buf);

                    // create a new item object if it doesn't exist yet
                    if(i==-1) {
                        item = new Item;
                        m_allItemsNames.append(item_buf);
                        item->setName(item_buf);
                        item->setPrice(item_price_buf);

                        m_allItems.push_back(item);
                    }

                    // use an existing item object
                    else {
                        for (int j=0; j < m_allItems.size(); j++) {
                            if(!m_allItems[j]->getName().compare(item_buf)) {
                                item = m_allItems[j];
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    //increment amount of items sold
                    item->setCount(item->getCount()+quantity_buf); 
                    sale->setItem(item);
                    m_allSalesOneVec.push_back(*sale);
                    day_vector.push_back(*sale);

                    //find the member
                    Member* mem = findMember(number_buf);

                    mem->setTotalSpent(mem->getTotalSpent()+quantity_buf*item_price_buf);

                    //if the current member is executive, add rebate
                    if(m_executiveMembers.contains(number_buf)) {
                        qInfo() << mem->getRebate();
                        mem->setRebate(mem->getRebate()+REBATE_PERCENT*quantity_buf*item_price_buf);
                    }

                }
                counter++;
            }
        }
        else {
            qDebug() << "File doesnt exists";
            return false;
        }
        m_allSales.push_back(day_vector);
}

Member* ManagementSystem::findMember(int id) {
    for(auto &mem : m_members){
        if(mem.getNumber() == id) {
            return &mem;
        }
    }
    qInfo() << "NOT FOUND";
    return nullptr;
}


void ManagementSystem::sortPurchasesByNumber() {
    std::sort(m_allSalesOneVec.begin(), m_allSalesOneVec.end(), [](Sale& a, Sale& b) {
        return a.getMembersID() < b.getMembersID();
    });
    return;
}

//sorting members (true - by id, false - by rebate)
void ManagementSystem::sortMembers(bool is_byID) {
    std::sort(m_members.begin(), m_members.end(), [&is_byID](Member& a, Member& b) {
        return is_byID ? a.getNumber() < b.getNumber() : a.getRebate() > b.getRebate();
    });
}

void ManagementSystem::addMemberToFile(Member& m) {
    QFile file(MEMBERS_FILE);
    if (file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Append)) {
        QTextStream stream(&file);
        stream << m.getName() << endl;
        stream << m.getNumber() << endl;
        static_cast<bool>(m.getType()) ? stream << "Executive" << endl : stream << "Regular" <<endl;
        stream << m.getDate().toString("dd/MM/yyyy") << endl;
    }
}
```

MainWindow is mostly just calling the ManagementSystem methods inside slots.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some things that may help you improve your program.  One positive thing I feel I must note is that you've used `const` consistently and appropriately to mark read-only member functions.  That's a very good practice and I hope you'll continue to do that as you go on!

### Use consistent case for `#include` files

Your operating system might not be case sensitive with respect to files, but many are.  To prevent problems with portability, instead of writing lines like this in `ManagementSystem.cpp`:

```
#include "managementsystem.h"
```

It should be this:

```
#include "ManagementSystem.h"
```

### Provide definitions for class members

In a number of classes, such as `Item`, there is a declaration for a construct such as `Item()` but no definition.  Either omit the declaration and allow the compiler to generate the constructor or tell the compiler (and the reader!) explicitly to do so:

```
Item() = default;
```

### Eliminate unused variables

There are several unused variables in the code, such as `type` in `ManagementSystem::populateMembersData()`.  Unused variables are a sign of poor quality code, and you don't want to write poor quality code. Your compiler is probably smart enough to tell you about this if you ask it nicely.

### Always `return` an appropriate value

Your `ManagementSystem::populateMembersData()` and `MangementSystem::populateDaySales` routines have control paths that cause them to end without `return`ing any `bool` value.  This is an error and should be fixed.

### Don't hardcode file names

Generally, it's not a good idea to hardcode a file name in software, and generally especially bad if it's an absolute file name (as contrasted with one with a relative path).  Instead, it might be better to allow the user of the program to specify the name, as with a command line parameter or configuration file.

### Think seriously about security

I understand that this is probably a project just for learning and exploring, but it's worthwhile to think about security provisions for this.  First, it appears that logins and passwords are stored unencrypted in both memory and in the credentials file.  Second, it's not clear how the logon is managed but the fact that the `ManagementSystem` class maintains its own `logged` flag telling whether an administrator or manager is logged in signals potential problems to me.  If there is a bug that forgets to clear that value when an administrator logs out, that's potentially a security problem.  Better might be to check the credentials of whomever is logged in every time higher privileges are needed which would also, potentially, take care of the risk that, say, a manager is demoted or fired while logged in but still has privileges on the system.  There are myriad other considerations, of course; this is just to help remind you to think in that direction.

### Use a `class` to maintain invariants

If a data structure has some invariant that it is enforcing, such as that if a membership type is changed, the date is reset, it makes sense to have that done via a `class`.  However, in the case of a class `Member`, where there are public setters and getters for every data item and no enforcement of any invariant, just make this a `struct` instead and eliminate a bunch of useless code.  This isn't Java.  See [C.131](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rh-get) for more details.

### Think carefully about object ownership

The `Sale` class currently maintains a pointer to an `Item`.  First, shouldn't that at least be a `const *` so that the `Sale` object can't alter the `Item`?  Second, what happens if the `Item` is deleted before the `Sale` class is?  It would mean that the `Sale` class instance would contain an invalid pointer.  Those problems could be eliminated by using something like a `std::shared_ptr`.

### Avoid C-style macros

There are few valid reasons left for using old-style C macros in modern C++ code.  Better is to create `const` or `constexpr` variables instead.  See [ES.31](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Res-macros2)

### Provide complete code to reviewers

This is not so much a change to the code as a change in how you present it to other people.  Without the full context of the code and an example of how to use it, it takes more effort for other people to understand your code.  This affects not only code reviews, but also maintenance of the code in the future, by you or by others.  One good way to address that is by the use of comments.  Another good technique is to include test code showing how your code is intended to be used.